# Управление глаголом

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Правильны ли выражения?

*"За всех заявлять не могу", "не заявляй за всех".*

Comment: Неправильно лошадей менять на переправе.

Answer (score 2):

Сочетание возможно. Я согласен, что всё зависит от смысла.

> Есть "заявил за всех". У Сергея Залыгина.

И не один.

> Сергей Залыгин. Комиссия (1976)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)
>
> ― Не откажемся! ― заявил за всех Игнашка. ― Мы тебя уважим, Зинаида 
>   Пална! [Сергей Залыгин. Комиссия (1976)] [омонимия не снята]
>   ←…→
>
> И. Н. Потапенко. Секретарь Его Превосходительства (1891)   [омонимия
>   не снята] Все примеры (1)
>
> Это само собой разумеется! ― заявил за всех Антон Петрович. Он 
>   принадлежал к тем пристрастным любителям музыки, которые с упоением
>   слушают то, что они почему-либо часто слышали, и совсем не признают
>   всего остального. [И. Н. Потапенко. Секретарь Его Превосходительства
>   (1891)] [омонимия не снята] ←…

Оба примера абсолютно нормативны. У Залыгина это слова автора, а текст 1891 г. вообще трудно заподозрить в просторечии.

Причина, как уже говорилось, в том, что выражение использовано в значении "заявить от имени всех". Глагольного управления тут нет. Глагол управляет именной группой с предлогом, а не предлогом как таковым.

Comment: Глагол управляет существительным с помощью предлога (предложное управление). Приводимые примеры - просторечная речь персонажа,  автор  использует этот прием для характеристики образа.

Comment: Заявить от имени - устойчивое выражение, например: "6-й областной съезд, состоявшийся в марте 1927 г., единодушно от имени всех трудящихся заявил, что действия указанной группы являются контрреволюционными". А теперь сделаем замену: "съезд ЗА ВСЕХ  трудящихся заявил... "  Хорошо звучит, "нормативно"?

Comment: @Sibylla *Хорошо звучит, "нормативно"?*. Вы меня спрашиваете? Я не предлагал заменять подобным образом. Для меня, простите, советская канцелярщина звучит плохо в любом случае, нормативна она или нет. Если вы возражаете против моего мнения о конструкции "за кого-чего", то,будет встречный вопрос. У Потапенко - звучит нормативно? Если нет, то почему.

Comment: Просторечное выражение  как художественный прием автора, выражающий иронию.  Довольно распространенный.

Comment: О как! Спасибо за цитату. У Потапенко - это явно не просторечие.   Там по смыслу "сделал заявку".Мне как-то это в голову не пришло, а ведь это аргумент. Источник тут.  http://az.lib.ru/p/potapenko_i_n/text_0030.shtml

Comment: @Sibylla почитайте источник - вряд ли будете настаивать, что это просторечие. Ни по стилю, ни по значению - ну никак не оно.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, как я понимаю, о предлоге "за" в этом сочетании? Контекст нужно смотреть.

Сами по себе таки выражения допустимы (на уровне, я думаю, разговорности) но только в одном значении: "[делать заявление] от имени всех, выражая мнение всех". Это значение предлога "за" проявляется в выражениях "работать за всех", "есть за всех".

Вот это значение у Кузнецова.

> 14. кого-что. Указывает на лицо, вместо или взамен которого кто-л. действует или от имени которого совершается действие. Поработать за
>       товарища. Расписаться за брата. // Указывает на занятие, ремесло,
>       специальность и т.п. того лица, чьи обязанности выполняет кто-л.
>       другой. Он правил за кучера.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0&all=x

Впрочем, даже в этом значении проще и правильнее, думаю, будет сказать "говорить/сказать за всех". В этом варианте выражение вполне нормативно: ***"не могу сказать за всех", "не говори за всех"***

Однако чаще всего сочетание "заявлять за всех" используется в ином смысле.

> 8. кого-что. (в сочет. с глаг.: бояться, волноваться, беспокоиться, радоваться и т.п.). Указывает на лицо, предмет, состояние и т.п.,
>      которые вызывают то или иное чувство, переживание. Бояться за чью-л.
>      жизнь. Радоваться за друга.

(там же).

Вот такое значение в сочетании с глаголом "заявлять" и подобных считаю неправильным. Здесь надо сказать "про всех", "обо всех". И тоже лучше не "заявлять", а "говорить": ***"не могу сказать обо всех"***.

Это значение предлога "за" в сочетании с глаголами "говорить", "сказать" известно из песни: "Не могу сказать за всю Одессу" и распространилось на многие другие, хотя даже в Одессе оно имеет очень узкую сферу применения.

Оно же иногда бытует в научной среде в сочетании "поправка за что-то" (за атмосферную рефракцию например), но дальше устных разговоров тоже не идет.

Так что "заявить за всех", с отрицанием или без, скорее всего или прямая ошибка, или стилизация - под "одесскую речь", или неуместный профессиональный жаргонизм.

Comment: "Поправка за атмосферную рефракцию" - это перебор. Это шутка, кажется, в "Физики шутят".

Comment: @Иванов7-й Ну если вам нужен источник "шутки", то это Петр Васильевич Маковецкий "Смотри в корень". Только пишет от там вполне серьезно. Но я опирался не на него, а на собственные воспоминания.

Comment: Точно! "Смотри в корень".

Answer (score 1):

**За всех заявлять не могу** ―  ненормативное сочетание, так как глагол "заявить" не образует падежных форм с предлогом ЗА:

**ЗАЯВИТЬ**, 1. **что (о чём).** Сообщить о чём-л.; сделать заявление. З. о своём решении. З. протест. З. претензию. Он заявил, что останется дома.

Поэтому в таких случаях следует использовать глагол "говорить": **За всех говорить не могу.**

**Примеры**

Я не берусь **говорить за всех** или даже за многих, Я. Е. Харон. Злые песни Гийома дю Вентре (1965).

Но только священник... божественною благодатию облечен правом и дерзновением **говорить за всех**. [протоиерей Георгий Флоровский(1929)]

Саша принужден был **говорить за всех**, и уже его веселость возвратила мало-помалу всем присутствие духа. [Р. М. Зотов. Два брата, или Москва в 1812 году. Часть I (1850)]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60272/discussion-on-answer-by-sibylla--).

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Причина изложена в комментарии. к ответу "Иванов 7-й". Автор объявил просторечием то, что никаким образом быть им не может, ни по содержания, ни по контексту вообще. Пишет образованный человек и общается тоже с образованными.